What would be the the mathematical equivalent of this excel formula? =PPMT() and =IPMT()
To calculate the EMI we have a formula called PMT() and we know the internal formula as well as mentioned in What would be the the mathematical equivalent of this excel formula? =PMT() but I also need the internal formula for interest i.e IPMT() and principal and PPMT() for each period.
Can anyone help me for the same.

You don't have time to reply whether it resolves the query or not ?

The mathematical formulas you would need are as follows:


• For IPMT()
= -(c * ((1 + r)^(per-1) - 1) / r + pv * (1 + r)^(per-1)) * r    



Where c is PMT()
Where r is Rate
Where per is Payment Number
Where pv is Present Value


• Formula used in cell C10
=-(C9*((1+B1/B2)^(B3-1)-1)/(B1/B2)+B5*(1+B1/B2)^(B3-1))*B1/B2


• For PPMT()
= c+(c * ((1 + r)^(per-1) - 1) / r + pv * (1 + r)^(per-1)) * r  


• Formula used in cell C11
=C9+(C9*((1+B1/B2)^(B3-1)-1)/(B1/B2)+B5*(1+B1/B2)^(B3-1))*B1/B2


Also refer the screenshots for more clarifications.

